# Refused to load the image 'https://diary2020.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

**I used MERN(MongoDb, Express, React js, Node) technology for my app. It works locally fine. but When I deployed in heroku I am getting internal server error. I might made mistake in setup but I can't see it.**

**In google Chrome console I got this error: Refused to load the image 'https://diary2020.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.**

**When I used Heroku logs I got this:**

[image]

**This is my server setup:**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const app = express();
const logs = require("./src/logs.js/logs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const path = require("path");
const helmet = require("helmet");
//middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());

//connect to db
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true
  })
  .then(() => console.log("DB Connected!"))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

app.use("/api", logs);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "build")); //
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "build", index.html));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running port ${port}`);
});
```

**In my client folder first run `npm run build` then I cut it and pasted it outside of the client. Then I connected to server. As you can above. But it does not recognize the build's index.html**

**This is my backend package.json**

```
{
  "name": "form",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "node server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "author": "alak",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^3.21.3",
    "heroku": "^7.39.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.3",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2", //I MISTAKENLY INSTALLED IT.BUT I THINK IT SHOULD NOT BE A PROBLEM
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0" //I MISTAKENLY INSTALLED IT. BUT I THINK IT SHOULD NOT BE A PROBLEM
  }
}
```

**This is React's package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "13.10.1",
    "npm": "6.13.7"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReferenceError` you're seeing is caused by `index.html` not being wrapped in quotations - node is trying to evaluate the `html` property of an object named `index` which I'm willing to bet is not what you meant.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "build")); //
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "build", index.html)); // <- try "index.html"
});
```

Comment: No sweat! Seeing as you’ve accepted the answer you might feel like editing the question since now that I read the answer the question doesn’t make sense to me :)

Comment: @boga how did you fix it??

Comment: @boga will you ps tell how did you fix it as I also stuck here

Answer (score 1):

The probable reason why you getting this error is likely because you've added /build folder to your .gitignore file or generally haven't checked it into git. So when you git push heroku master, build folder you're referencing don't get push to heroku. And that's it shows this error.
T its work properly locally